# unexpected behaviour with dates

Tags: mysql

I am trying to list all the months between two dates in Mysql and ended up with the following:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS ( 
    SELECT start_date as period, end_date 
    FROM progetti WHERE id = 1 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATE_ADD(period, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), end_date FROM dates WHERE period < end_date ) 
SELECT * from dates;
```

That returns:

| period | end date |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 2022-03-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 2022-05-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 2022-06-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 2022-07-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 2022-08-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 2022-09-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 2022-11-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 2022-12-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |

Why do I also get the last row? isn't 2023-01-01 greater than 2022-12-31?
The same happens with any set of dates. I always get one record more.

Comment: @Akina can you elaborate on this? How can I get rid of the last row?

Comment: @mandy8055 how is this supposed to help? you are widening the range instead of limiting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last row is a selection from pre-last row where `2022-12-01` is less than `2022-12-31`.

If `day` component in `start_date` may differ from `01` then you must use complex query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS ( 
    SELECT start_date, start_date as period, end_date, 1 as rn
    FROM progetti 
    WHERE id = 1 
  UNION ALL 
    SELECT start_date, start_date + INTERVAL rn MONTH, end_date, rn + 1
    FROM dates 
    WHERE period <= end_date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
SELECT period, end_date 
FROM dates;
```

This avoids `day` deviation (for example, if `start_date = '2022-01-31` then all next rows will contain `28` in `day` component of the date).

https://dbfiddle.uk/eViMoI9c

Answer (score 1):

When its arrive to period `2022-12-01` the comparaison `WHERE period < end_date` will be translated to WHERE '2022-12-01' < '2022-12-31' which is true then as result you will get also `2023-01-01` :

To exclude `2023-01-01` try this :

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS 
(
    SELECT start_date as period, end_date
    FROM progetti
    WHERE id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD(period, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), end_date
    FROM dates 
    WHERE DATE_ADD(period, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) < end_date
)
SELECT *
FROM dates
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/DTJ6ewEA)

Answer (score 0):

Even though `2023-01-01` is greater than `2022-12-31`, the condition `period < end_date` is still true since `2023-01-01` is considered less than `2022-12-31` for the purpose of the recursive query. This happens because you are comparing the individual months without considering the year.

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS ( 
    SELECT start_date as period, end_date 
    FROM progetti WHERE id = 1 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATE_ADD(period, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), end_date FROM dates WHERE 
    YEAR(period) < YEAR(end_date) OR 
    (YEAR(period) = YEAR(end_date) AND MONTH(period) < MONTH(end_date))
) 
SELECT * from dates;
```